# QuickMapServices QGIS showing nothing

Tags: qgis, basemap, quickmapservices

I have downloaded the QuickMapServices Plugin for QGIS, however when I try to open an OSM layer (or any layer) nothing happens. It appears in the legend, but not in the project workspace (other layers are working fine).
I also cannot access the Contributed Pack, as it says there is an error in the python code.

If anyone else has had this problem, is there a solution?

Comment: What version of QGIS and version of QuickMapServices plugin you have installed? If you set the project CRS to EPSG:3857 the layer is rendered? Can you copy in the question the message showed at the Log Messages panel, tabs Plugins and Python Warnings?

Comment: It's QGIS 3.2.2 and QuickMapServices 0.19.10.1 - the error message I'm getting reads An error has occurred while executing Python code: 

AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'exc_type'